# How do I connect to the KomTrax API?

Tags: python-requests, postman

I'm having trouble understanding how to make requests to an API. See the snippet below from the providers API documentation:

[image: API Provider "GET ACCESS TOKEN" instructions]

The URL to get an access token is: https://komtraxisoapi.azure-api.net/provider/token

Apologies, I know this may seem trivial to some, but how do I set-up Postman to make this request for a token ?

Also, how would I make this request using the Python requests package ?

I have tried making a request using Postman using OAuth2 authentication, API provider documentation states that the API follows ISO 15143-3 standards.

Comment: Can you share API documentation URL?

Answer (score 0):

In Postman, click the 'Collections' button on the left hand side, then click the '+' button to add a new collection and give it a name.

Next click the 'Variables' tab. I would usually define the base URL here, so create a variable with the name "base_url" and give it an initial value of "https://komtraxisoapi.azure-api.net/provider/".

Add a new request to the collection. Change the type of request from 'GET' to 'POST' and set the URL to be "{{base_url}}/token".

Click the 'Body' tab, then click the radio button 'x-www-form-urlencoded'. Now you need to add your parameters. Add a key "grant_type" with a value of "password". Then add two more keys with the names "userName" and "password". These should have the values supplied by Komatsu. Note that what they refer to as 'Account' is the username.

Hitting the 'Send' button should now return a token as 'access_token' in the result pane.

You can add another request to Postman for the fleet endpoint. This time it would be a 'GET' request and your URL would be something like "{{base_url}}/v1/SomeNumber/Fleet/1", replace "SomeNumber" to match that in the URL supplied by Komatsu.

Click the 'Authorization' tab and set the 'Type' to 'Bearer Token' and the 'Token' value to the 'access_token' value from the previous token request result - it'll be a long string of numbers and letters.

Hitting 'Send' on this request will pull back a list of equipment in AEMP standard, compatible with ISO 15143-3.

Python isn't my usual programming language, but this snippet will print the access token.

```
import requests
import json

base_url = "https://komtraxisoapi.azure-api.net/provider/"

response = requests.post(base_url + "token", data={"grant_type": "password", "userName": "<account>", "password": "<password>"})

if response.status_code == 200:
    jsonData = json.loads(response.content)
    print(jsonData['access_token'])
```